Looking for a book about a South American father and son who travel to Paris and visit a family with the same name?
From what I remember:

The father and son travel, and wherever they go the father looks for a family with the same name as theirs in the phone book and contacts them.
I'm fairly certain they travel to Paris.
The family they visit comprise a father and son.


Welcome to the site. Can you remember any other details such as how old the story might be, details from the cover, what language was it written in? Any detail can help our expert identifiers!

I eventually managed to track it down when I remembered a character's name. It's Distant Relations by Carlos Fuentes. From Goodreads:

the story moves across time and space, from Latin America to Europe, from generation to generation. We hear of Hugo, a noted Mexican archeologist, and of his young son, Victor, who were once the Count's houseguests. He tells of their time in France, of their complicated pasts and their uncertain relationships.


Hi Janine, it looks like you've created two separate accounts here. That's OK, the answer is valid (although it could be expanded), but please check out how to merge your accounts, because you'll need access to the original account in order to accept your own answer and mark the question as solved.
